# Install package `auto-latex-completion`

Tags: package, auto-complete-mode

I am totally new to Emacs (I just began some days ago) and my purpose is to use it for Latex. I tried to install package `auto-complete-auctex` doing this :

1) I copy file `auto-complete-auctex.el` to my `/.emacs.d` folder ;

2) In Emacs shell I did `M-x load-file` and then put the path to the `auto-complete-auctex.el` file.

3) Then I get the message

`Cannot open load file: aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type, tex`

It seems that the way to install package is not direct one for me, as I am so new to Emacs...

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "in Emacs shell"?

Answer (score 0):

Have you a `init.el` in `.emacs.d`? In the `.emacs.d` put `auto-complete-auctex.el`.

Then in your `init.el` you need to load the file and load the package:

```
;; Load the file
(load auto-complete-auctex)

;; Load the package
(require 'auto-complete-auctex)
```

And from your `init.el` do `M-x load-file`. Otherwise restart Emacs.

See [Loading from EmacsLisp](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/LoadingLispFiles).

Else you can install packages with `package.el`: `M-x package-list-packages`: [Install packages](http://pragmaticemacs.com/emacs/install-packages/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did put the instructions you mention in my init.el file. Then when starting Emacs in `--debug-init` mode I got : Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-variable auto-complete-auctex) (load auto-complete-auctex) eval-buffer(#<buffer *load*> nil "/home/yggdrasil/.emacs.d/init.el" nil t) ; Reading at buffer position 45 load-with-code-conversion("/home/yggdrasil/.emacs.d/init.el fat" "/home/yggdrasil/.emacs.d/init.el" t t) load("/home/yggdrasil/.emacs.d/init" t t) In fact, the `auto-completion-auctex` package is not in the list of package when I do `M-x package-list-packages`

Comment: This is not an answer.  Please put this kind of additional info directly in your question (since you can edit it).